# javascript me muestra undefined cuando quiero pintar mi grafica

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql

Hola que tal buenas tardes, javascript me muestra mi consulta `undefined`, lo que quiero hacer es pintar mi gráfica, ya le busque pero no encuentro la solución, espero y me puedan ayudar gracias, o si hay otra solución, para no hacerlo de esa manera.

Este es mi script llamado `lineal.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "consulta_reporte.php",

    success : function(data){
      alert(data);

      var sample_id = [];
      var expected_value_reporte = [];
      var min_2std_reporte = [];
      var plus_2std_reporte = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        sample_id.push(data[i].sample_id);
        expected_value_reporte.push(data[i].expected_value);
        min_2std_reporte.push(data[i].min_2std);
        plus_2std_reporte.push(data[i].plus_2std);
      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: sample_id,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "expected_value",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            data: expected_value_reporte
          },
          {
            label: "min_2std",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            data: min_2std_reporte
          },
          {
            label: "plus_2std",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            data: plus_2std_reporte
          } 
        ]
      };

      var ctx = $("#resultado");

      var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata
      });
    },
    error : function(data) {

    }
  });
});
```

Y mi consulta php es este, aquí lo que hago es llamar una consulta anidada donde selecciono tres combos y al ultimo muestro la gráfica, con este script que dejo a continuación.

```
<?php

?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <html>
  <head>
    <title> Generar Reporte</title>

    <style>
      .chart-container {
        width: 640px;
        height: auto;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="linegraph.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>


    <?php

    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = '5432';
    $database = 'pos';
    $user = 'postgres';
    $password = '';

    $cnx = pg_connect(
      'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database .
      ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password
  );

    $qr = "select * from vw_dhqc_report";

    $year = 'year';
    $id_control = 'id_control';
    $element = 'element';



    // header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
    $query4 = "SELECT
        DISTINCT year, id_control, element,
        returned_value, expected_value,
        sample_id, min_2std, plus_3std, plus_2std
      FROM vw_dhqc_report
      WHERE
      '$_POST[$year]' = year AND 
      '$_POST[$id_control]'= id_control AND
      '$_POST[$element]'= element
    ";
    $result4 = pg_query($query4);

    ?>
    <?php

    $resutado = array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result4)) {
      $resutado[] = $row;
    }
    http_response_code(200);
    header("Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8");
    // echo json_encode($resutado);
    pg_close($cnx);




    ?>

    <div class="chart-container">
      <canvas id="resultado"></canvas>
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

este es mi index.php donde lleno los combos

```
  <form  id="formulario" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Seleccione una Opci&oacute;n<h3>
    <!-- <h3>year</h3> -->
    <select name="year" id="year_id">
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <?php
     $query = "select distinct $year from vw_dhqc_report order by year desc";
     $result = pg_query($query);

     while($fila=pg_fetch_array($result)){
     echo "<option value='".$fila['year']."'>".$fila['year']."</option>";
     }
    ?>
    </select>
    <!-- <h3>id_control</h3> -->
    <select name="id_control" id="control_id">
    <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
     </select>
     <!-- <h3>Element</h3> -->
     <select name="element" id="element_id">
    <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
     </select>
    <br><br>
      <?php

      ?>
    </form>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#year_id').on('change', function(){
            var year = $(this).val();
            if(year){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: 'control.php',
                    data:'year='+year,
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#control_id').html(data);   
                  }   

                }); 
            }else{
                $('#control_id').html('<option value="">Select year</option>');
            }
        });

    $('#control_id').on('change', function(){
            var id_control = $(this).val();
            var year =$('#year_id').val();

            // var  element = {'year':year,'id_control':id_control};
            if(id_control){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'element.php',
                     data: element = {'year':year,'id_control':id_control},

                    success:function(data){
                        $('#element_id').html(data);


                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#element_id').html('<div value="">Select id_control</div>');
            }
         });
      $('#element_id').on('change', function(){
            var id_element = $(this).val();
            var year =$('#year_id').val();
             var id_control =  $('#control_id').val();

            if(id_element){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'consulta_reporte.php',

                    data: element = {'element':id_element,'year':year,'id_control':id_control},

                    success:function(data){
                        $('#resultado').html(data);


                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#resultado').html('<div value="">Mostrar Tabla</div>');
            }
         });
        });
      </script>

<div id="resultado">

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Unas preguntas rápidas. ¿Ese es tódo tu código HTML? Surgen 2 cositas a simple vista. 1º El JavaScript se recomienda llamarlo al final del html, antes de cerrar la etiqueta <body>, a no ser que se indique estrictamente lo contrario. En segundo lugar, veo que ese script llamado "lineal.js", no lo estás llamando en el HTML. Llamas a linegraph.js, que no se si es al que te referías. Finalmente, podrías confirmar que tu consulta SQL de php regresa lo que tiene que regresar?, para descartar y centrarnos en el JS

Comment: Si es correcto así se llama mi JS pero regresando al comentario tengo otro script PHP donde lleno mis combos

Comment: Te puedo escribir a un correo amigo y te paso lo demás para revisar porfavor

Comment: Intenta exponer toda la pregunta aquí, eliminando las partes sensibles o innecesarias del código. Deja lo imprescindible pero realista, es decir, donde estas cargando todos los Javascript en tu HTML. Tu primer script llamado "lineal.js" no se ve en tu HTML, por ejemplo.

Comment: este es mi index donde cargo los combos

Comment: Genial!!, ahora podemos ver exactamente que tienes e intentar encontrar el problema. Has probado a cambiar el orden del javascript? Intenta organizar y llamar todo el código javascript al final, justo antes de ```</body>```, debajo de ```<div id="resultado"></div>```. Por otra parte, intenta poner la librería JQuery antes que ninguna otra, y el resto debajo.

Comment: si ya lo intente pero me manda vacio la informacion

Comment: los valores en la grafica me aparecesn  undefined, y ya hice todo bien, no se a que se deba

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver en tu código la variable **chartdata** es la que llena tu gráfico has comprobado si se esta llenando el valor de forma correcta eso lo pueden comprobar con console.log(chartdata) y dando F12 en el navegador puedes ver el resultado. verifica por favor eso

Comment: si lo hice y no devuelve nada, como lo puedo solucionar

Comment: me seria de gran ayuda   gracias

Comment: en la grafica me sigue mostrando undefined no me trae nada